# Response.AddHeader

Tags: asp.net-2.0, response.addheader

When is `Response.AddHeader` used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's used to add additional [HTTP Headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers) to your request-- read the previous link if you're unfamiliar wtih what an HTTP Header is used for.

Most of the time, you'll end up setting headers indirectly, using other ASP.NET objects or methods like `Response.Cookies` or `Response.Redirect`.  However, there are advanced, relatively unusual scenarios where it's sometimes necessary to call `Response.AddHeader()` directly in your code.

For example, to cause an HTTP 301 (permanent) redirect in ASP.NET 3.5, you'd need to use `Response.AddHeader`, using code like this:

```
<script runat="server">
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.AddHeader("Location","/newpage.aspx");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just one example of Justin Grant's answer is if you want to output excel you can do the following:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.xls");
```